# CodeDeploy Blue/Green Deployment listener port at API gateway?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-application-load-balancer, blue-green-deployment

I am working on a complicated structure on AWS, which includes an API gateway for users connecting the website located inside a VPC. In this VPC, I have planned to use ALB to load balancing the traffic from outside to different ECS Fargate tasks.

For own purpose, I have planned to use Blue/Green Deployment in CodeDeploy session for deploying the services located in ECS fargate. From the documentations of AWS, I understand the listener port of production and test environment can be set up at load balancer.

I would like to know whether the listener port can be set up at API gateway. As I hope to use CloudFormation for this approach, it would be better related to it. Thanks!

Comment: CodeDeploy does not deploy to API gateway. Cloud you clarify what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @Marcin Where do CodeDeploy actually deploy to? I would like to know whether the blue/green deployment can be set up to allocate the traffic at the API gateway part, not alb.

Comment: It deploys to ECS, EC2 and lambda. API gateway has its own deployment mechanism through [canary deployments](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/canary-release.html).

Comment: is it possible to create two API gateway with one ALB respectively, then each ALB attach with blue or green environment? Coz I want to enter blue or green environment by different URL, not port.